# Java JPanel.add(...) not working

Tags: java, swing, awt

Here is my code I have written thus far, along with the errors I'm receiving. I'm sure I've done similar code before with no errors. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something stupid but I can't figure it out or find anything on the web.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton editButton = new JButton("Edit");
    JPanel.add(editButton);
}
```

Error:

```
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s) - for the underlined '.' 
on the last line
Syntax error on token "editButton", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this 
token - for the underlined parameter within the brackets on the last line.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use it as if it's a *static* method - which panel would you expect to add the edit button to? You need to call it *on* the `mainPanel`:

```
mainPanel.add(editButton);
```

However, you can't do that in a class declaration - a statement like that has to be in a method or constructor. So you probably want:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {       
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton editButton = new JButton("Edit");

    public MyFrame() {
        mainPanel.add(editButton);
    }
}
```

Or possibly put *all* the initialization into the constructor, and also make the variables final and private:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame {       
    private final JPanel mainPanel;
    private final JButton editButton;

    public MyFrame() {
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        editButton = new JButton("Edit");
        mainPanel.add(editButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i knew it was something stupid, this is because i'm trying to rush code, I even typed my question wrong thanks to rushing. I meant to put mainPanel.add() which also wasn't working, but you've answered that anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use it as follows.

```
mainPanel.add(editButton);
```

---

You must call it through it's object and not with associating it with its class name as it is not a **static** method.